Failed to resolve import "#app/composables/script-stubs (Vitest)
I am receiving the error 'Failed to resolve import "#app/composables/script-stubs"' inside the .nuxt folder in the imports.d.ts file
My code is like this and I've tried importing everything... and I still get this error. How to fix it?
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue(),
        Components({
            dts: true,
            types: [{
                from: 'vue-router',
                names: ['RouterLink', 'RouterView'],
            }],
            dirs: ['./components'], // Auto-importará tudo dentro da pasta components
        }),
        AutoImport({
            imports: [
                'vue',
                'vitest',
                'pinia',
                "vue-router-composables",
                "vitepress"

            ],
            dirs: ['./composables', './stores', './utils'], // Escolha quais pastas deseja auto-importar
            dts: true,
        }),
    ],
    test: {
        globals: true,
        environment: 'happy-dom',
        include: ['__tests__/**/*.spec.ts'], // Ajuste o caminho conforme sua estrutura
        coverage: {
            all: true,
        },
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': '/',
            '~': '/',
            '#app': path.resolve(__dirname, './.nuxt/imports.d.ts'),
            '#vue-router': path.resolve(__dirname, './.nuxt/imports.d.ts'),
            'vue-demi': path.resolve(__dirname, './.nuxt/imports.d.ts'),
            '#app/composables/script-stubs': path.resolve(__dirname, './.nuxt/imports.d.ts'),
            '#app/components/nuxt-link': path.resolve(__dirname, './.nuxt/imports.d.ts'),
            '#app/nuxt': path.resolve(__dirname, './.nuxt/imports.d.ts'),
            '#app/compat/idle-callback': path.resolve(__dirname, './.nuxt/imports.d.ts'),
        },
    },
    publicDir: 'public',

});

